# send JSON data to Mongodb collection using spring boot

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, bson

So I have a MongoDB with 3 collections, call it tb1, tb2, tb3. I am trying to send JSON data to specific MongoDB collections. Here is what I got so far:

For each collection, I create a class, say Tb1:

```
@Document(collection = "tb1")
public class Tb1{}
```

And for each Tb, I create a MongoRepository interface:

```
public interface Tb1Repo extends MongoRepository<Tb1, String> {}
```

For the code where I insert:

```
@Autowired
private Tb1Repo repository;

try {repository.insert(Document.parse(message));}
catch(Exception e){
    log.info("not valid json object."+e.getMessage());
}
```

After that I retrieve data from tb1:

```
for (Document dc : repository.findAll()) {
    System.out.println(dc);
}
```

Is the logic correct? 
Also, I got error when I use repository.insert(...). It tells me that cannot resolve symbol.

Please, any help is appreciated.

Edit: I tried Low level operation this time. So here is the code :

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("dbtest");
MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("AccountAggregation");
```

One last question, if I am connecting to an AWS MongoDb with such configuration in my property file:

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=${MongoDBHost:xyz.aws.com}
spring.data.mongodb.port=${MongoDBPort:27017}
spring.data.mongodb.database=dbtest
spring.data.mongodb.username=adm
spring.data.mongodb.password=pswd
```

How do I specify that in my MongoClient?

Comment: Is that a compile time error ? `repository.insert()` requires an object for type `Tb1`. Do you require to save the bson data directly ? If yes you have to use the low level mongo db java driver interface to do so; if no just create a `Tb1` pojo and you can save it through repository insert method.

Comment: @Veeram Thank you that certainly cleared my thoughts. Yes the data needs to be bson. I updated my code please have a look. It still has some problems.

Comment: Np. You're mixing the old and new api. Try `MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();

        MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase("dbtest");

        MongoCollection<Document> collection = db.getCollection("tb1");

        collection.insertOne(Document.parse(message));`

Comment: @Veeram hmm it still gives me the same error..What if I want to send JSON to collection?

Comment: No it cant give you the same error. Check carefully. Its same for JSON too.

Comment: @Veeram Is it possible that I forgot to import files or there is something wrong with the configuration? Because it shows that collection.findall() is also fault.      `symbol:   method insert(Document)
  location: variable collection of type MongoCollection<Document>.`

Comment: it is `insertOne` method not `insert`

Comment: @Veeram RIGHT!! I have one last question about⬆️

Comment: Spring boot will create `MongoClient` for you. Just autowire `MongoTemplate` to preform CRUD operations. If you only need to insert JSON data directly you are better of using MongoClient directly and pass all the properties as args when you instantiate MongoClient.

Comment: @Veeram thanks you saved my day.